# PyQt, How to change BoxLayout's weight (size)

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I have a Gui layout as in the picture. 
[image]

So currently Sublayout1 and Sublayout2 are equal in size. However I want to make Sublayout1's width smaller and stretch Sublayout2's width bigger. Is there a way to do it dynamically instead of putting a fixed size. Like on Android Studio where you can set the weight of the elements within the layout.

Also affecting the size shouldn't affect the Bottomlayout either. Many thanks for your help. A snippet of the code is:

```
sublayout1 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
sublayout2 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
plotBox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
plotBox.addLayout(sublayout1)
plotBox.addLayout(sublayout2) 
bottomlayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
mainlayout.addLayout(plotBox)
mainlayout.addLayout(bottomlayout)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `stretch` parameter passed to [`QBoxLayout::addLayout`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qboxlayout.html#addLayout)

```
sublayout1 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
sublayout2 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
plotBox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
plotBox.addLayout(sublayout1, 1)
plotBox.addLayout(sublayout2, 2)
bottomlayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
mainlayout.addLayout(plotBox)
mainlayout.addLayout(bottomlayout)
```

In the above `sublayout2` has a stretch twice that of `sublayout1` and so should be allocated more space.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for. I added that to to the plotBox layout and it works just fine. But then I tried the mainlayout which is vertical, I put the stretch on the bottom 2 lines. It didn't change anything. Does vertical layout have a different way of adjusting stretch?

Comment: Assuming `mainlayout` is just a vertically aligned `QBoxLayout` then the same technique should work just fine.  Not sure why it wouldn't.